# How to convert a sql return to a custom Object?

Tags: javascript, sql, jsobject

In my code I make a SELECT on an SQL table where parameters are stored and I would like to output an OBJECT in this way:

```
{
  inscription_max: 0,
  inscription_open: false,
  liste_attente_max: 0
}
```

SQL Return :

```
[
  RowDataPacket { setting: 'inscription_max', value: '0' },
  RowDataPacket { setting: 'inscription_open', value: 'false' },
  RowDataPacket { setting: 'liste_attente_max', value: '0' } 
]
```

If you need more information, don't hesitate.
I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reduce for an array that will add a new field to resulting object for every array element : smth like this

```
let data = [
  { setting: 'inscription_max', value: '0' },
  { setting: 'inscription_open', value: 'false' },
  { setting: 'liste_attente_max', value: '0' } 
]

data.reduce((acc, rec) => ({...acc, [rec.setting] : rec.value}), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `.map()` each object to a variant of the current object, where the `setting` value is the key of the new object and the value of the `value` property is the value of the new object. You can also use `JSON.parse(value)` to ensure its string version is parsed to its primitive value (see second example). Then you can use `Object.assign()` with the spread syntax to build an object from your new array of objects:

```js
const arr = [
  { setting: 'inscription_max', value: '0' },
  { setting: 'inscription_open', value: 'false' },
  { setting: 'liste_attente_max', value: '0' } 
];

const res = Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(({setting, value}) => ({[setting]: value})));
console.log(res);
```

If you can support `Object.fromEntries()`, the same result can be achieved with a little less code:

```js
const arr = [
  { setting: 'inscription_max', value: '0' },
  { setting: 'inscription_open', value: 'false' },
  { setting: 'liste_attente_max', value: '0' } 
];

const res = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(({setting, value}) => [setting, JSON.parse(value)]));
console.log(res);
```

The above can be written more elegantly, as pointed out by [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas):

```js
const arr = [ { setting: 'inscription_max', value: '0' }, { setting: 'inscription_open', value: 'false' }, { setting: 'liste_attente_max', value: '0' } ];

const res = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(Object.values)); // credit to: @Andreas
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `const res = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(Object.values))`

Comment: @Andreas that's very clean, I like that (should consider adding an answer perhaps, otherwise I'm happy to add it in above if you're alright with that?)

Comment: Sure, just add it to yours.